# What causes "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."for this code?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, linked-list

```
class Node
{
    public Node next;
    public int data;

    public Node(int d)
    {
        this.data = d;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node n1 = new Node(10);
        Node n2 = null;

        Node root = n1;

        int count = 1;

        while (count < Int32.MaxValue -1)
        {
            n2 = new Node(count); //Exception
            n1.next = n2;

            n1 = n2;
            count++;

         }
```

}

The exception occurs when the system memory has reached 3 of 16GB

Comment: Int32.MaxValue is a large value 2^31-1 = 2 147 483 647, you need to multiply that with the memory for each node.

Comment: Your system memory has run out of exceptions - it's all in the error message!

Comment: If your creatin 2.1 billion of anything you may want to recosider how you store this, Perhaps you should be using SQL, however I wold love to see these nodes written out to an xml file :)

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit OS, with 4GT tuning enabled? This could explain why you get the exception when the virtual memory of the process reaches 3GB.

Answer (score 4):

As other commenters have said, Int32.MaxValue is a large number (approximately 2.4 billion), and each Node requires at least 8 bytes header - all .NET objects have this - plus four more for the Node reference, plus another four for the int (on a 32-bit system; on x64, those numbers become 16, 8, and 4 respectively). Multiplying up, that means this program is trying to allocate something like 36GB of memory just in Node objects, which would be sufficient to explain why you can't run it on a 16GB system.

On 32-bit Windows, however, before you even get that far you're going to run into problems with the process address space.  (You'll run into similar ones with other 32-bit operating systems, since it is to a large extent an artifact of the underlying hardware.)  On 32-bit windows, each process gets 4GB, of which 2GB is needed by the kernel, and the process itself gets 2GB.  You can configure that by changing an OS setting to 1GB kernel, 3GB for the process.

And this latter restriction is why you hit OutOfMemoryException well before using up all 16GB of your physical RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.First, I need to reopen the question and rephrase the title to "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

Answer (score 0):

Int32.MaxValue is a laaaarge number and you are creating new instances of Node times that number. Most probably that overwhelmes the amount of memory you have available or the amount of memory permitted by the OS for a process to have.

Comment: no it s not a large number:) however, VM arranges more memory for objects.